# How to replace a line with another line in PHP using its number

Tags: php

hope that you're doing well, I'm trying to implement a script so that I can use it to replace a line with another one in a file, I tried a lot of PHP scripts  and Bash codes but they all seem to failed, here what I tried last:

```
function replace_a_line() {
    $line=3; //includes zero as 1.
    $newdata='this is a test 123';
    $data=file('./txt.txt');
    $data[$line]=$newdata."\r\n";
    $data=implode($data);
    file_put_contents('./txt.txt',$data);
}
```

My file name is **txt.txt**

Thank you in advance

Comment: So what happens when you run this function? I would expect that you get the whole contents in a single line.

Comment: Did the below answer work? _If yes_ , check the tick mark next to it so that future researchers know that it is a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost did it. No need to implode it yourself. [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) does it for you.
Add additional checks to make sure line number is something within the number of lines range or append the text to the end.

```
<?php

function replace_a_line($line = 3,$new_str = 'Your text') {
    $data = file('test.txt');    
    if($line >= count($data)) $data[] = $new_str;
    else  $data[ $line - 1] = $new_str . "\n";
    return file_put_contents('test.txt', $data, LOCK_EX);
}

replace_a_line();
```